# pandas data frame / numpy array - roll without aggregate function

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, python-3.7

rolling in python aggregates data:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']], columns=['a','b'])
y = x.rolling(2).mean()
print(y)
```

gives:

```
     a  b
0  NaN  a
1  1.5  b
2  2.5  c
3  3.5  d
```

what I need is 3 dimension dataframes (or numpy arrays) shifting 3 samples by 1 step (in this example):

```
[
  [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']],
  [[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']]
]
```

**Whats the right way to do it for 900 samples shifting by 1 each step?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.concantenate`

```
np.concatenate([x.values[:-1], 
                x.values[1:]], axis=1)\
  .reshape([x.shape[0] - 1, x.shape[1], -1])
```

Comment: what would it look like if samples num is 900 instead of 2, shift is 1 as in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try of concatenating window length associated dataframes based on the window length chosen (as selected 2)

```
length = df.dropna().shape[0]-1
cols = len(df.columns)
pd.concat([df.shift(1),df],axis=1).dropna().astype(int,errors='ignore').values.reshape((length,cols,2))
```

Out:

```
array([[[1, 'a'],
        [2, 'b']],

       [[2, 'b'],
        [3, 'c']],

       [[3, 'c'],
        [4, 'd']]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know whether this solution suits your question.

```
p = x[['a','b']].values.tolist()  # create a list of list ,as [i.a,i.b] for every i row in x
#### Output  ####
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]


#iterate through list except last two and for every i, fetch p[i],p[i+1],p[i+2] into a list
list_of_3 = [[p[i],p[i+1],p[i+2]] for i in range(len(p)-2)]

#### Output  ####
[
    [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']],
    [[2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
]



# This is used if in case the list you require is numpy ndarray
from numpy import array
a = array(list_of_3)

#### Output  ####
[[['1' 'a']
  ['2' 'b']
  ['3' 'c']]

 [['2' 'b']
  ['3' 'c']
  ['4' 'd']]
]
```

Comment: I really need number of samples to be a variable. It is 900 today. I didn't know python devs are so into hardcoding things. its not like I am looking into writing `[p[i],p[i+1],p[i+2]` 300 times. but thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas `1.1` you can iterate over rolling objects:

```
[window.values.tolist() for window in x.rolling(3) if window.shape[0] == 3]
```

The `if` makes sure we only get *full* windows. This solution has the advantage that you can use any parameter of the handy `rolling` function of pandas.